# using pandas str.split where the occurrence needs to be value of column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, split

Having some troubles figuring out pandas str.split. Where the occurrence comes from a column value instead of placing one static value for the string to be split on.  I have looked around on this sight for similar type questions but most seem to just have a static approach to the split.

Below I have dataframe.  The .str.split('|',1).str[-1] will remove the left part of the string at the first occurrence of the pipe('|'). This static approach will perform the same down through the series. Because the occurrence argument does not change.

What I would like to happen: The .str.split('|',**df['occurrence']**).str[-1] could be dynamic and utilize the value within the occurrence column and be used as the str.split occurrence argument. **And if value is zero or less then no action is taken on string.**

The lambda statement actually works and performs correctly however, it starts from the right side of string, splits and joins based on the value between the pipes. But the final outcome is good. Different approach. I just can't make it do the same thing from the left side of the string.

Last point to make: The removal needs to start from the left of string.

```
#-------------------
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import numpy as np

data_1 = {'occurrence': [7,2,0,3,4,0],
        'string': ['1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12','10|11.2|12.2|13.6|14.7','1|2|3',
                   '1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8','1|2.4|3|4.6|5|6.2|7|8.1','1|2|3|4|5'] }

df = pd.DataFrame(data_1)


df['string'] = df['string'].str.split('|',1).str[-1]  # Works but is static only

# df['string'] = df['string'].str.split('|',df['occurrence']).str[-1]  # Trying to use occurrence 
                                                                       # column value as argument

# Does work BUT starts with right side of string. Needs to be left.
# df['string'] = df.apply(lambda x: '|'.join(x['string'].split('|')[:x.occurrence - 2]), axis=1) 


print(df)
#-------------------

Start with:                                        What I would like:
occurrence   string                                occurrence    string   
7            1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12            7             8|9|10|11|12
2            10|11.2|12.2|13.6|14.7                2             12.2|13.6|14.7 
0            1|2|3                                 0             1|2|3 
3            1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8                       3             4|5|6|7|8 
4            1|2.4|3|4.6|5|6.2|7|8.1               4             5|6.2|7|8.1
0            1|2|3|4|5                             0             1|2|3|4|5
```

I would appreciate any light that you can shine on this subject for me to work through this problem. As always your time is valuable and I Thank You for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Series.str.split` to split the column `string` around delimiter `|`, then use `zip` to zip the splited column with `occurence` inside a list comprehension and process the values:

```
df['string'] = ['|'.join(s[i:]) for i, s in zip(df['occurrence'], df['string'].str.split('|'))]
```

Result:

```
print(df)
   occurrence          string
0           7    8|9|10|11|12
1           2  12.2|13.6|14.7
2           0           1|2|3
3           3       4|5|6|7|8
4           4     5|6.2|7|8.1
5           0       1|2|3|4|5
```

---

Performance (measured using `timeit`):

```
df.shape
(60000, 2)

%%timeit -n10
_ = ['|'.join(s[i:]) for i, s in zip(df['occurrence'], df['string'].str.split('|'))]
67.9 ms ± 2.05 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit -n10 (using 'apply')
_ = df.apply(lambda x: '|'.join(x['string'].split('|')[x.occurrence:]), axis=1)
1.93 s ± 34.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham, worked nicely. I haven't seen zip used with a split.  I appreciate your time with this and the explanation of the process.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your lambda expression to:

```
df.apply(lambda x: '|'.join(x['string'].split('|')[x.occurrence:]), axis=1)
```

If you want the later elements(right-side), you should start from the occurrence as the index.

Result:

```
0      8|9|10|11|12
1    12.2|13.6|14.7
2             1|2|3
3         4|5|6|7|8
4       5|6.2|7|8.1
5         1|2|3|4|5
```

Comment: Hello Kartik,  Thank you for taking the time to answer.  I'm interested in your lambda approach to this however, I could not get your line to do anything when used with the above example. Strange, I see your results. But when I run it is as if your line is not there...no errors just prints occurrence & string column. Any thoughts what I'm doing wrong or things to check?

Comment: Did you do the assignment ?
`df['string'] = df.apply(lambda x: '|'.join(x['string'].split('|')[x.occurrence:]), axis=1)`

Comment: Ha,  seriously 'My-Bad'.  Good Catch Kartik.!!!!  Impressive....I was racking my brain with that lambda line.  I have so much to learn. Thanks for your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat unorthodox approach: build a regex from `df['occurrence']` and use this to match:

```
df['regex'] = df['occurrence'].map(lambda o: '^' + r'(?:[^|]*\|)'*o + r'(.*)$')   
df['regex']

0    ^(?:[^|]*\|)(?:[^|]*\|)(?:[^|]*\|)(?:[^|]*\|)(...
1                         ^(?:[^|]*\|)(?:[^|]*\|)(.*)$
2                                               ^(.*)$
3              ^(?:[^|]*\|)(?:[^|]*\|)(?:[^|]*\|)(.*)$
4    ^(?:[^|]*\|)(?:[^|]*\|)(?:[^|]*\|)(?:[^|]*\|)(...
5                                               ^(.*)$
Name: regex, dtype: object
```

Now just apply `re.match` to each row:

```
df.apply(lambda row: re.match(row['regex'], row['string']).group(1), axis=1) 

0      8|9|10|11|12
1    12.2|13.6|14.7
2             1|2|3
3         4|5|6|7|8
4       5|6.2|7|8.1
5         1|2|3|4|5
dtype: object
```

Comment: Hey BallpointBen, what a unique approach to my problem. Unfortunately, I was not able to get it working. It is probably me not understanding the how to's.  When running your two lines, I achieve your first result window as a final result on my side.  The re.match line on my window (pycharm) does not convert back the string like your 2nd result window. Thanks for taking the time. I do appreciate it.